# Cannot pass object to php with js ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, object

I create js object:

```
   var taskTypes = {};


    $(".task_types_tags_category").each(function () {
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        name = name.replace("[]","");
        var typeId = $(this).val();
        var currentTagsCount =0;
        var currentTags = [];
       if($(this).is(":checked")){
           taskTypes[typeId]={};
           taskTypes[typeId]=[typeId];
       }
       $('input[name="'+name+'[task_types_tags][]"]').each(function () {
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                currentTags.push($(this).val());
                ++currentTagsCount;
            }
        });
       if(currentTagsCount >0){
           taskTypes[typeId]={};
           taskTypes[typeId]=[typeId];
           taskTypes[typeId]["tags"]={};
           taskTypes[typeId].tags = currentTags;
       }
    });

    console.log(taskTypes);
```

I need pass `taskTypes` object to php.
In console I get right object:
https://clip2net.com/s/3RZXM4b

Then I try pass object:

```
$.post(sJSUrlSaveLeadNote, {taskTypes:taskTypes},
        function (data) {

        }, "json");
```

Php file:

```
 show($_REQUEST['taskTypes']);
```

But In php I just get it (cant get tags key):
https://clip2net.com/s/3RZXQaK

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `JSON.stringify( taskTypes )` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying `taskTypes[typeId]["tags"] = {}; taskTypes[typeId].tags = currentTags;` try this `taskTypes["tags"] = {}; taskTypes.tags = currentTags;` because in your code your actually adding a tags attribute to your first array, which does not get properly parsed by jQuery.